# How to write Regular Expression for BSON Object in c++?

Tags: c++, regex, mongodb, bson

I am having BSON object like this,

```
{ "0" : "Kollywood", "1" : "Tollywood" }
```

I am going to use this bson object $in query in mongo db to get all matched tags without case sensitive. but i am getting exactly matched result alone.

{

```
    "result": [
        {
            "_id": 110, 
            "tags": [
                {
                    "id": "5524cdfffe13b4934bbd6cab", 
                    "name": "Kollywood"
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "ok": 1
}
```

My requirement is,(All matched tags without case sensitive)

```
{

        "result": [
            {
                "_id": 110, 
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "id": "5524cdfffe13b4934bbd6cab", 
                        "name": "Kollywood"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "5524cdfffe13b4934bbd6cab", 
                        "name": "KollyWOOD"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ], 
        "ok": 1
    }
```

How can i do this in c++?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`{ "0" : "Kollywood", "1" : "Tollywood" }` this is the query object, i have to convert this as a following manner

```
            {
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "tags.name": {
                            "$regex": "^kolly wood", 
                            "$options": "xi"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "tags.name": {
                            "$regex": "^tolly wood", 
                            "$options": "xi"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Comment: This is not C++ way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code you can use:

```
string inp = "{\r\n\r\n    \"result\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"_id\": 110, \r\n            \"tags\": [\r\n                {\r\n                    \"id\": \"5524cdfffe13b4934bbd6cab\", \r\n                    \"name\": \"Kollywood\"\r\n                }\r\n            ]\r\n        }\r\n    ], \r\n    \"ok\": 1\r\n}";
string regx = "(\"tags\":[\\s\\r\\n]+\\[[\\s\\r\\n]+)(\\{[\\s\\r\\n]+\"id\":[\\s\\r\\n]+\"[^\"]*?\",[\\s\\r\\n]+\"name\":[\\s\\r\\n]+\")([^\"]*?)(\"[\\s\\r\\n]+\\})";
regex rxg(regx);
string reslt = regex_replace(inp, rxg, "$1$2$3},\r\n                $2KollyWOOD$4");
std::cout << reslt << endl;
```

Result:

[image]